# WordPress not logging PHP errors in files outside the normal WordPress paths

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress install where I've set:

```
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

in `wp-config.php`. It all works great, and PHP errors are logged to `/wp-content/debug.log`.

I've got a few of my own PHP files in another folder on the server that access WordPress data but are loaded from direct URLs. Unfortunately, errors in those aren't logged to `debug.log`. For example, if I make a file called `/myscripts/test.php`, and then put in it:

```
<?php 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';

cause error
?>
```

then this file causes a 500 error when loaded (as expected) but there's nothing in `debug.log` about what happened and it's a bit irritating to debug. Am I doing this wrong? Is this not the way to load WordPress inside an "external" PHP file?

Comment: Even if u create error inside wp-load and wp-config, and you call it by runing your custom php script that has wp-load included, it still wont log error.

If its possible to somehow link your custom php file during dev phase to file that is loaded with wp, plugin file or functions.php, that would work, but i suppose thats not an option.

Comment: wp-load gives the error? Im not too sure on the implementation of wp-debug, I assume its setting php values for error conf so nothing you can't do yourself before calling the file to see what's up...or set it in .htaccess php value.. `php_value log_errors 1    php_value error_log  xxPATHxx